# How to send ether to the smart contract from an ethereum address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, payable

I would like to automatically after an event occurs to withdraw an amount of money from a certain ethereum address and keep the money with the contract. How can I do this? Any hint is appreciated.

I tried calling an internal payable function from my contract POD_PhysicalItems:

Here is how I call it, sender is an ethereum address defined in the constructor, but there is an error at the line below Type error Member "value" not found or not visible after argument dependent look up in the function address:

```
POD_PhysicalItems.withdrawAgreedUponCollateral.value(2*itemPrice)(sender);
```

This is the function:

```
 function withdrawAgreedUponCollateral(address entityAddress) payable internal  {
    require(state == contractState.DoneVerificationofTerms);
    collateralWithdrawnSuccessfully("Double deposit is withdrawn successfully from: ", entityAddress);

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you're trying to accomplish please? Do you mean send money from an ethereum address to the contract? What do you have so far/what have you tried?

Comment: So you have an address that is defined in the constructor of the contract. And when an event occurs, you want that address to send ether to `entityAddress`? Do i understand correctly?

Comment: @Chris I want the address which is the entityAddress or sender (same thing) to send ether to the contract itself

Comment: @Chris entity address is the name of the argument taken bu the payable function and sender is the ethereum address that is passed when the function is called

Comment: So you would just do that in web3. If `entityAddress` is the same address as the sender, you don't need the argument because you can just reference `msg.sender`. I answered a similar question here, lemme know if this helps: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43022/a-bit-confused-how-do-i-send-ether-using-web3j-to-an-address/43026#43026

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74674/discussion-between-haya-raed-and-chris).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this over chat with the following example:

[image: example]

Comment: explained "you can't just withdraw directly from those accounts. this is because the only way for money to come from an account is for that account to explicitly sign a transaction send some value to the contract."